# Bessel Integrals in Matern Covariance from Whittle, 1963

Tags: integration, bessel-functions

In the paper "Stochastic Processes in Several Dimensions" by Peter Whittle (1963), the following definitions and integration appear as equations (3.14) and (3.15). $n$ is the dimensionality of the space.
$J$ is Bessel function and $K$ is modified Bessel funciton of the second kind. I checked the [Digital Library of Mathematical Functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10) but there's so much stuff there that I'm just lost.

If anyone can shed some light on the following derivation, I'd be thankful.

$$
f_{\xi}(\vec{\nu}) := \frac{1}{(|\vec{\nu}|^2 + a^2)^{2p}}
$$

\begin{align}
\Gamma_{\xi} (|\vec{s}|) 
&= \frac{1}{(2\pi)^n} \int e^{i \langle \vec\nu, \vec s \rangle } f_{\xi}(\vec \nu) d\vec\nu \\
&= \frac{s^{(-n/2) + 1}}{ (2\pi)^{n/2} } \int_{0}^{\infty} \frac{ J_{(n/2)-1}(\nu s) \nu^{n/2} d\nu}{ (\nu^2 + \alpha^2)^{2p}} \\
&=\frac{ (s/\alpha)^{2p-n/2}K_{2p-n/2}(\alpha s)}{2^{2p-1} \Gamma(2p)}
\end{align}

### If you want the paper

The paper took some effort to find by Carol Hutchins, the amazing (former) librarian at the Courant Institute, so if you want to look at the original you can email me (firstname.lastname@gmail.com). Also, if I emailed you this paper, feel free to leave a comment with your contact, in case someone else wants this paper and cannot reach me.

Comment: Hello! Do you still have the paper with you?

Comment: @Ponciopo of course, just HMU

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understand correctly, $f_\xi(\nu)$ is a function of the modulus of $\nu$, only, then $\Gamma_\xi(s)$ is the n-dimensional radial Fourier transform (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_transform#Relation_to_the_Fourier_transform_.28circularly_symmetric_case.29) or [here](http://math.arizona.edu/~faris/methodsweb/hankel.pdf) for example), it is then a Hankel transform. Finally, the modified Bessel function is tabulated in [DLMF](http://dlmf.nist.gov/10.22.E46).

Comment: Thank you for your answer but it does not help me. The (inverse) FT part is obvious (and even if not, can be taken as definition). I'm looking for insight on the two last equalities.

Comment: What do you need? The Fourier transform of a radially symmetric in n-dimensions gives the penultimate equality as given in the references cited and the last one is exactly tabulated.

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't careful. Thank you for your answer.